# load Pdf while change values in combobox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to load PDF pages while choose different  combo-box values without refreshing page
like

```
            <select>
                   <option >page1.pdf</option>
                   <option >page2.pdf</option>  
            </select>
```

While  choose page1.PDF I want to load PDF in the same page without reload

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't think you can render a PDF in the middle of an HTML document (though I could be mistaken, there may be some HTML5 element which might do this?), but one approach you might take is to render the selected PDF in an `iframe`.

Comment: Sth like http://jsfiddle.net/z37nd6me/ ? Leave more details

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution with Javascript: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Then you can try to launch a new view with PDF loaded, or load it in the same page with JS or JQuery